# How to open Google Doc in WebView?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, google-drive-api

I am developing a Google Drive app for Windows 8. I need to open Google Docs in WebView. I am using this URL. `GoogleDoc` is an object deserialized from JSON.

```
GoogleDoc.alternateLink + "&access_token=" + AccessToken
```

`https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1sRwH0rixxxxxxxxxxxxxxxPJNKkySUb-70vlM/edit?usp=drivesdk&access_token=ya29.1.AADtN_XfpEPIkTxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxqUaFsovWAgYbdL56Nw`

The above link opens the doc for few seconds & then prompts "You are signed out, you need to sign in again." The sign-in button never works.

[image]

So can't I use the access token in `WebView` or user need to login one more time in `WebView`?